# Entity Framework 5 database namespaces

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an existing database that has tables in a few different database schemas. Some of the tables in the different schemas have the same name, so I may have a User table in schema a and schema b. I can create two diagrams in my single .edmx file and map the namespaces to different diagrams, but only one entity is generated by my t4 tempaltes.

How is this case normally handled in entity framework? Is there a way to specify namespaces when the entities are generated?

Comment: I know you can do this with code-first, I'm not too sure if there's a way with an EDMX.

Comment: I will look into doing this with code first - I have not done much with it in the past but it looks promising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no, if you add all schemas in same .edmx mdoel.

Try to add another .edmx file in another folder or project, add tables of other schema to it and then go through the following:

1) From the `solution explorer` window, right-click on `model.tt` file and choose `Properties`.

2) In prop. window set the `Custom Tool Namespace` property to the desired namespace.

3) And finally, right-click on `model.tt` again and click on `run custom tool`.

After that, you'll see that the namespace of your `model.tt` POCOs are changed.

Comment: I suppose I could create another edmx file, but then I need to add tables from other schema's when they are related to each other (such as an account/login schema) and then I run into the same issue again.